# Why can't I close my RadioGroup tag in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple app in Android Studio and I am using RadioButton and RadioGroup widgets. The problem is after a I use the RadioGroup tag, I can't close the tag. When I try typing `</RadioGroup>` to close the tag, it is automatically replaced with `</LinearLayout>` which closes the LinearLayout tag. How should I try to close the RadioGroup tag after adding RadioButtons inside it?

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/rbtm"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/rbtf"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Note that I want to close the RadioGroup tag after the RadioButtons; not before them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot '>' after opening the RadioGroup tag

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Pls vote and make it as helpful if it's really helpful to help others find the right answer.

Comment: Sure. Just waiting for the 10 minute timer :)

Answer (score 0):

Before implementing RadioButton, RadioGroup must be closed, and after that you can create the two RadioButtons.

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</RadioGroup>
```

After this you can create inside of RadioGroup:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RadioGroup>
```